# OpenCV detect color Automatically

Tags: opencv

Is there a possible way to make Color Blob Detection automatically detect a specified color without pressing it ?

Ex I'll just specify what range of color is I want then it would automatically detect the color with the same range.

Comment: What do you mean by ```pressing it```. Also: define color-range!

Comment: Color blob detection works by pressing the screen and detect same color of what was being pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `cv::inRange` and define your range of colors as (r1,g1,b1) to (r2,g2,b2). E.g.:

```
cv::inRange(input, cv::Scalar(0,140,0), cv::Scalar(160,255, 160), output);
```

Comment: what is the color inRange for yellow ?

Comment: @Shulz: Scalar(0,100,100) to Scalar(100,255,255)