# Is there any way or API present in OpenCV to List out the coordinates (mat.at(x,y)) which is matched with given input value with tolerance?

Tags: c++, opencv

Is the any better way to get List of coordinates with matched input values from the **cv::Mat** through **opencv API**?

```
findCoordinateListByMatchValue(Mat& img , double Value , int tolerance )
{
    for (int i = 0; i<img.rows; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<img.cols; j++)
        {
            if(img.at<double>(i, j) >= Value-tolerance && img.at<double>(i, j) <= Value+tolerance  )
            {
                //Store matched coordinates list (i, j)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // return matched coordinates list (i, j)
}
```

This will take loge time to process the Large images.
Does anyone have an idea about this query ?

Comment: why it is double? your image float type?

Comment: yes ,32 bit float type of images

Comment: [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html) is what you need I think. These are the ways which helps to reach the pixels

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV detect color Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461044/opencv-detect-color-automatically)

Comment: @ zteffi Thanks lot I will try it for my float type images :)

Comment: @zteffi  "void inRange(InputArray src, InputArray lowerb, InputArray upperb, OutputArray dst)" in the inRange function "dst – output array of the same size as src and CV_8U type."  its supports only  CV_8U type i think as per documentation . for my case output array gives wrong matrix value